# Prove that a ring $R$ with no non-trivial right ideals and $aR=0$ has $|R|=p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring such that $R$ has no non-trivial right ideals. If there exists a nonzero element $a \in R$ with $aR=0$, prove that $|R|= p$ where $p$ is prime.

Comment: Maybe you mean "it has no non-trivial right ideal"?

Comment: In my opinion this exercise makes no sense, since a ring (with unity) with prime order is necessarily a finite field, and finite fields have no annihilators.

Comment: We don't khow it has prime order. Also it hasn't unity.

Comment: @erfansoheil I know you said "right ideal" early on, but I just want to make sure you aren't assuming commutativity. Is this the case?

Comment: @rschwieb, the ring isn't commutative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $I=\{b\in R:bR=0\}$. This is a right ideal and then $I=0$ or $I=R$. By hypothesis $I\ne 0$, so $I=R$.

Thus we have $xy=0$ for all $x,y\in R$. Then $(R,+)$ is an abelian group with no nontrivial subgroups, so $|R|=p$ a prime number.